# NodeJS error trying to find data in mongo DB: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, authentication

I am doing an application with a login in a MEAN stack. One of the features of this login is the social login, the point is that when a new user wants to enter in the app with facebook I have to check if this facebook is already recorded in my mongoDB or not to do that I have hereunder code:

From the frontend page:
1.- Login-Page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router"
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";

// Login con Google & Facebook
import { SocialAuthService } from "angularx-social-login";
import { FacebookLoginProvider, GoogleLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";

import { SocialUser } from "angularx-social-login";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  socialuser : SocialUser;
  loggedIn: boolean;

  user = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  }

  options = []

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private socialauthService: SocialAuthService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socialauthService.authState.subscribe((socialuser) => {
      this.socialuser = socialuser;
      this.user = {
        name : this.socialuser.name,
        email : this.socialuser.email,
        password: "DefaultExample"
      }
      this.authService.log(this.user)
      .subscribe(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.token)
        this.router.navigateByUrl("home");
      })
      this.loggedIn = (socialuser != null);
    });
  }

  signInWithGoogle() {
    this.socialauthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  signInWithFB() {
    this.socialauthService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

}
```

2.- The authentication service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private URL = "http://localhost:3000/api"

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  signUp(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + "/signup", user);
  }

  signIn(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + "/signin", user);
  }

  log(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + "/login", user);
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.router.navigate(["/login"])
  }

}
```

And in the backend I have:

```
const { Router} = require("express");
const router = Router();

const User = require("../models/user");
const userCtrl = require("../controllers/user.controller")

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(("calvazo"))
    const {name,typeuser, email, password } = req.body;
    const newUser = new User({name,typeuser, email, password});
    await newUser.save();
    
    const token = jwt.sign( {_id: newUser._id }, "secretKey" );
    res.status(200).json({token})
});


router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("ENTRO")
    const email = req.body.email;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    
    if(!user) {
        console.log("E-mail not found")
        const newUser = new User({name,typeuser, email});
        await newUser.save();
        console.log("New User added")
        const token = jwt.sign( {_id: newUser._id }, "secretKey" );
        res.status(200).json({token})
    }
    console.log("E-mail in DB")
    const token = jwt.sign( {_id: user._id }, "secretKey");
    res.status(200).json({token});
});

router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    
    if(!user) return res.status(401).send("the email does not exist / Mis cojones morenillos")
    if (user.password !== password) return res.status(401).send("wrong password");
    
    const token = jwt.sign( {_id: user._id }, "secretKey");
    res.status(200).json({token});
});



module.exports = router;

function verifytoken(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send("Authorization denied");
    }
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    if(token === "null") {
        return res.status(401).send("Authorization denied");
    }

    const payload = jwt.verify(token, "secretKey")
    req.userId = payload._id
    next();
}
```

when I use my app and it tries to check the code it appears this issue from the backend size:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25607) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Do you know why?

Also, I would like to ask through here, for securing my app I am using guard, do you know more techniques to protect it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node doesn't give you much of a trace for uncaught errors thrown from async code. If you were doing async promise-style, you'd want to have a `.catch()` on your promise to catch errors so that you can see and handle them. For async/await you'd wrap the suspect code in try/catch blocks.

I'd recommend wrapping your middleware bodies in `try...catch`, so that any unhandled middleware error can get caught and reported while also sending back a meaningful response to the client (e.g. a 500 error). For example:

```js
router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({email})
    
        if(!user) return res.status(401).send("the email does not exist / Mis cojones morenillos")
        if (user.password !== password) return res.status(401).send("wrong password");
    
        const token = jwt.sign( {_id: user._id }, "secretKey");
        res.status(200).json({token});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err); // Or however you want to log it to see what's going on
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

In general, if something *can* have an error in async code, that error should be getting caught by something. Otherwise as your codebase grows it can become quite the nightmare to track down one of these mysterious, trace-free errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! doing that I ve been able to detect the issue!